# MySql #1054 error while executing it through phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1054

I am trying to execute this code in phpMyAdmin. But, I'm getting following error

#1054 - Unknown column 'year' in 'field list'

```
SELECT
  CONCAT('SELECT year2,',
  GROUP_CONCAT(sums),
  ' FROM yourtable GROUP BY year2')
FROM (
SELECT CONCAT('SUM(name=\'', name, '\') AS `', name, '`') sums
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) s
INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Check out [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9f31/1) for implementation.

How to fix this?
And any ideas how do I script in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Year` is a known object in MYSQL, if you have a column named 'year', try it with a back-tick '`'::

```
SELECT
  CONCAT('SELECT `year`,',
  GROUP_CONCAT(sums),
  ' FROM yourtable GROUP BY `year`')
FROM (
SELECT CONCAT('SUM(name=\'', name, '\') AS `', name, '`') sums
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) s
INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```